# Dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I have the example of grouped select:

```
SELECT cod, value, type 
FROM table
GROUP BY cod, value, type
```

I get results:

```
cod | value | type
1   | 1000  | A
1   | 570   | B
2   | 2000  | A
3   | 1500  | A
3   | 200   | B
```

But for only `cod = 1` should return value from `type = A`. Desired result:

```
cod | value | type
1   | 1000  | A
2   | 2000  | A
3   | 1500  | A
3   | 200   | B
```

i think the `CASE` statement in `WHERE` but have limitations and doesn't works correctly. How i can do it?

```
WHERE CASE WHEN cod = 1 THEN type = 'A' END
```

Comment: Do you want type arbitrarily set to A for all `cod = 1`, or do you want to exclude data where `type = A and cod <> 1`?

Comment: I want get only value for `type = A` from `cod = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE Type = CASE WHEN cod = 1 THEN 'A' else Type END
```

Comment: First = or the 2nd or 3rd?

Comment: 2nd, after `THEN`

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
SELECT cod, value, type 
FROM table
WHERE cod != 1 OR type='A'
GROUP BY cod, value, type
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good option - Not the best way here but a helpful option.

```
SELECT cod, value, type 
FROM table
GROUP BY cod, value, type

EXCEPT

SELECT cod, value, type 
FROM table
WHERE cod = 1 AND type <> 'A'
GROUP BY cod, value, type
```